# HowTo programmatically remove <mat-error> element in "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12"

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular4-forms

I am using a Custom method to display my errors. However, my errors are not displayed flushed with the input error line (due to I think, the presence of the mat-error element)?? My errors are pushed down about 20px below the error line.

Is there some way I could programmatically remove this element?

Cheers and thanks

Comment: You could use CSS `display:none`

Comment: Using `<mat-error style='display: none;'></mat-error>` does not remove the gap.

Comment: Then the gap might come from somewhere else. Hard to tell from here.